# Does Leave Travel Allowance claimed for one calendar year includes the return fare?

Tags: income-tax, india

Suppose between Sept 20, 2021 and Sept 23, 2021, I travel from Mumbai to Chennai having ticket cost as Rs.6000 and back to Mumbai having ticket cost as Rs.5000. So, while filing LTA for the FY 2021-22 can I claim the ticket costs of both the journeys i.e. total Rs.11000 as Leave Travel Allowance in one calendar year ?

Please help.

Comment: Your question is very specific, but I doubt remuneration for actual costs incurred, is going to be labelled "allowance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Both side travel is included.

Note: dont trust financial advice on internet. You are liable for all risks you take and decisions you make.